# publishing to Artifactory from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to publish to an Artifactory (v4.5.1) instance using a Jenkins(v2.7) pipeline.  An excerpt from my script is below.  Problem seems to be that the "Artifactory" object is not recognized and is treated as a string. Can someone suggest what the problem might be?

```java
node {
 //error - "Artifactory" treated as String 
 def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID

  def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "hello-pipeline/build/libs/*.jar",
                "target": "jenkins-local"
            }
        ]
    }"""

  def buildInfo1 = server.upload spec: uploadSpec
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is as I have never used `Jenkins Artifactory plugin`, but as you seem to be deploying Java artefacts, do you know you can use standard [Maven deploy task to deploy your artefact to Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/video/setting-up-artifactory-4-as-a-maven-repository-in-minutes/) ?

Comment: what version of artifactory plugin are you using?
most probably it is related

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with the syntax:

```
node {
 def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID

  def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [{
                "pattern": "hello-pipeline/build/libs/*.jar",
                "target": "jenkins-local"
            }
        ]
    }"""

  server.upload(uploadSpec)
}
```

as was suggested on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46835485/3893015). However, this could be an issue with your version, as mention in the [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878620/publishing-to-artifactory-from-jenkins-pipeline?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment65121131_38878620) above.