# Artifactory - Use Jenkins Pipeline script to upload

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm trying to upload some binaries to Artifactory by using Jenkins Pipeline script.
I used the same exemple from Artifactory [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins), but it doesn't work.
I had the following error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.upload() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [{
              "files": [
                       ....
```

There is another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878620/publishing-to-artifactory-from-jenkins-pipeline) but there is no response...

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        def server = Artifactory.server 'art-1'
        def uploadSpec = """{
              "files": [
                {
                   "pattern": "path/",
                    "target": "path/"
                }
             ]
            }"""

    }
    stages {
        stage('upload') {
           steps {
              script { server.upload(uploadSpec) }

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Artifactory 5.4.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't using the declarative pipeline quite right. The environment section doesn't work like that. You can only define strings in there, and I would have thought that `def` would throw an error, but apparently not.

You are likely ending up with `server` being equal to a String representation of the reference to an Artifactory.server object. Basically Artifactory.server.toString().

Try this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('upload') {
           steps {
              script { 
                 def server = Artifactory.server 'art-1'
                 def uploadSpec = """{
                    "files": [{
                       "pattern": "path/",
                       "target": "path/"
                    }]
                 }"""

                 server.upload(uploadSpec) 
               }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where I was using the correct syntax, and not seeing any errors, but still not seeing an artifact uploaded. Instead of a Jenkins log like:

```
[Pipeline] { (upload)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
[libraries_PR-1-WWJNY63HBCEAKKTFO6WL2V5LW] Running batch script
[Pipeline] getArtifactoryServer
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] artifactoryUpload
[consumer_0] Deploying artifact: https://my.artifactory.net/path/
[Pipeline] }
```

I was seeing:

```
[Pipeline] { (upload)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
[libraries_PR-1-WWJNY63HBCEAKKTFO6WL2V5LW] Running batch script
[Pipeline] getArtifactoryServer
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] artifactoryUpload
[Pipeline] }
```

This was because my path wasn't specified correctly, so no files matched it. Changing the path caused everything to work.